# Disabling every input on a page programmatically in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have tried searching around for this, but what I found was mainly for disabling a single input type.

What I want to do is disable every input type on a single page. Everything. Textboxes, checkboxes the whole lot.

I couldnt figure out how to modify the loops I found, which is why I am asking here, beacause it's likely one of you has a piece of code laying around that can do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below if you like to do it in javascript/jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

OR try below if you want in asp.net

ach control has child controls, so you'd need to use recursion to reach them all:

```
protected void DisableControls(Control parent, bool State) {
    foreach(Control c in parent.Controls) {
        if (c is DropDownList) {
            ((DropDownList)(c)).Enabled = State;
        }

        DisableControls(c, State);
    }
}
Then call it like so:

protected void Event_Name(...) {
    DisableControls(Page,false); // use whatever top-most control has all the dropdowns or just the page control
} // divs, tables etc. can be called through adding runat="server" property
```